# How to prevent bootstrap tabs from interfering with angularjs routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

When using AngularJS and bootstrap javascript tabs, I ran into an issue of where angularjs route would pickup href clicks. In a result, instead of showing a tab, route redirects to location of where tab button is lining to. In short, bootstrap javascript tab is not suppressing default action for tab clicks.

Comment: If you aren't already using AngularJS directives for your Bootstrap components, I'd start there. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap

Comment: As mentioned above use the angularized versions of thee bootstrap components from here - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 4):

Just add  `target="_self"

See example:

```
<a href="#tab01"  target="_self" >
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab01">show tab1</div>
```